# Calculate the frequency of combinations from a set of binary variables

Tags: r, combinations, frequency

Is there a way to calculate the frequency of combinations from a set of binary variables?

```
a <- c(0,1,0,1,0)
b <- c(1,1,0,1,0)
c <- c(0,1,0,0,0)

> data.frame(a, b, c)
  a b c
1 0 1 0
2 1 1 1
3 0 0 0
4 1 1 0
5 0 0 0
```

In this example, combination a + b is the most common, since obj. 2 and 4 have these. I only want to count combinations with at least 2 variables containing [1]. Is there a way to calculate this ?
I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas!

My expected output should be like this:

```
combinations


1 ab  2
2 ac  1
3 bc  1
4 abc 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
> X <- data.frame(a, b, c)
> apply(model.matrix(data=X, ~a*b*c), 2, sum)[-(1:4)]

 a:b   a:c   b:c a:b:c 
    2     1     1     1
```

`model.matrix` will encode all of the interactions in your dataset for each row, then I used apply to sum the rows.  The first four elements were the intercept and main effects `a`, `b`, and `c` which you didn't need.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help

```
unlist(
  sapply(
    2:3,
    function(k) {
      setNames(
        combn(df, k, function(x) sum(Reduce("*", x))),
        combn(names(df), k, toString)
      )
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   a, b    a, c    b, c a, b, c 
      2       1       1       1
```

## data

```
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

Comment: I'm solely getting NAs on my main dataset, is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option. First get all combinations of your data.frame names, then using `lapply` on each of the combinations, check the `rowSums` to see if that combination is present in the data.frame, and `sum` up all of those found.

```
res <- unlist(Map(combn, list(names(df)), 2:3, simplify = F), recursive = F)
unlist(lapply(res, function(x) {
  setNames(data.frame(sum(as.integer(rowSums(df[,x] == 1, na.rm = T) == length(x)))),
                      paste0(x, collapse = ''))
}), use.names = T)
```

**Output**

```
 ab  ac  bc abc 
  2   1   1   1
```